# Google Map API - evaluating circles with getMap() or setMap()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to have a button that can toggle multiple circles on and off (show / hide visibility). Assuming I just have a html button and i have added a google.maps.event.addDomListener to that button, A lot of examples I have seen use setMap() to determine if the circle is already there.

```
if(circle.setMap() != null){ 
    circle.setMap(null);
}else{
    circle.setMap(map);
}
```

This however only removes the circle but will not add it back once the button is clicked again. If the circle is not NULL and evaluates as such, I than set the circle to null. How is it that when the button is clicked a second time circle.setMap() != null SHOULD be false, but it just keeps running the if statement not the else.

I was able to fix it by using getMap() instead so..

```
if(circle.getMap() != null){ 
    circle.setMap(null);
}else{
    circle.setMap(map);
}
```

What exactly is getMap() doing? Why when i see it in so many examples (even for polylines and rectangles) does getMap() != null NOT work???

My second question is, would this be the correct way to do this? Or would I be better off just setting the fill and stroke opacity to 0 instead? Also the way I have done it above by using setMap(null) to hide circle and setMap(map) to show it, how does the map know what parameters to use for re-adding/showing the circle? I ask this as my zindex for the circles forces them below some polylines I drew, but when i hide the circle than show it again it is over top of the polylines but still the correct size and location?

Thanks for any incite!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMap()` only returns `null` when you set the map-property to `null`

When you don't set the map-property it returns `undefined`

Simply check if the returnValue of `getMap()` evaluates to `true` or `false`

```
if(circle.getMap()){ 
    circle.setMap(null);
}else{
    circle.setMap(map);
}
```

Related to the 2nd question:

Instead of `setMap` use `setVisible` to show/hide the shapes:

```
if(circle.getVisible()){ 
    circle.setVisible(false);
}else{
    circle.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: oh ok, so is setMap() actually setting the value of getMap() for a given circle? And why do so many examples use setMap() instead of getMap() to check if the circle is already there? As in   if(setMap() != nuill){do stuff}

Comment: I don't know which examples use `setMap` to check if a circle is there....`setMap` returns nothing, so it's not good for checking anything. It's just a setter-method.